# Cypress - how to describe a multiple step test

Tags: cypress

This is probably an anti-pattern, but I'm new to e2e testing and I'm not sure there's a way around my requirements.

I have the need to test a scenario in my system that is several steps long (maybe 50-60 steps). This means going to about 15-20 pages, clicking and entering various details, and seeing the results. The reason the requirement is so long is that the system processes orders from creating an order, creating line items with various details, and running it through a long production process. My most valuable test would be to run through the whole process and verify the results.

I can't find a good way of isolating, say, steps 40-42 to verify that this process alone works well, because to get an order in that state I'd have to run through the first 39 steps.

Is there a good way to write tests to cover this scenario?

Comment: If you have tests to check the 15-20 pages of clicking and entering various details, then you would benefit from having an API to submit all those details to save time. The dev or qa team might know of existing APIs.

Comment: I'm actually in the process now of converting this legacy system from .Net WebForms to a Web API backend and Angular frontend. It's actually the process of building those APIs that are causing issues I would like to test.